# How to change color of string being drawn on JPanel

Tags: java, string, fonts, colors, jpanel

Hi, I am trying to change the font color for a string that is being drawn on my JPanel. How do I make my font color be black instead of white?

Here is how I am drawing:

```
g.setFont(font);
g.drawString("Rating: " + Integer.toString(rating), 150, 150);
```

Here is the font:

```
 private static final java.awt.Font verdana_12 = new java.awt.Font("Verdana", java.awt.Font.BOLD, 14);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe read [the documentation for the Graphics class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html)?

Comment: Completely overlooked the setColor method. Thank you.

Comment: `g.setColor(Color.BLUE);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the color in a JPanel or most things in Java Swing, there is a function available called `.setColor(Color c)`. For your code, you would do:

`g.setColor(Color.BLACK)`

Here is a helpful link with more explanation:
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/java.awt/Graphics/0940__Graphics.setColor_Color_c_.htm

This website also has other links so answer more Java Swing questions.